# Text box change text on submit

Tags: html, text

When the user hits submit, it will show a different text in the box based on user input. For example: "www.link.com/page".

Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name="comments" cols="25" rows="5">
page
</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is this a real question?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this (if this is what you are trying to do) :**

```
<input type="text" id="txtInput" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="    javascript: document.getElementById('comments').value = document.getElementById('txtInput').value;" /><br />
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="25" rows="5">
    page
</textarea>
```

If you are trying to do something else, please provide more details. :)